# How to activate my touchpad features on Samsung Series 7 Chronos

Tags: 12.10, touchpad, samsung, multi-touch

I'm just looking to how enable the features of my touchpad on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.10. The mouse is working but none of the features are working (like two fingers scrolling up/down).

I visited some tutorials like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9

It works until I set the psmouse protocol. The section on system setting > mouse and touchepad > 'touchpad' dissapeared; I dont really understand why. Can you help me please?